# Difference between transient parent and parent in qt

Tags: qt, qt5

I got confused with parent and transient parent in qt.

1. Whether for same window is it possible to have both transient and parent ?
2. For Top level window (widgets like Popup) transient parents are set and parent set to NULL ?

Can you please share clear idea about parent and transient parent in qt.

Answer (score 5):

> Whether for same window is it possible to have both transient and parent?

Yes, but it's a special case. Recall that a `QWindow` (and also `QWidget`) is-a `QObject`. So you may wish to give it a parent for the purpose of memory management or abstract ownership, but not for the purpose of window management.

Thus a `QWindow` (and `QWidget`) can have a parent **and** also be a top-level window by setting the `Qt::Window` window flag. Otherwise, all parent-less windows and widgets have that flag set by default - and it can't be cleared.

If such a window is **also a transient window** (e.g. a popup), then it can have a transient parent that will be different than the normal parent.

> For Top level window (widgets like Popup) transient parents are set and parent set to `nullptr`?

Generally yes, but see above - you can **also** set their `parent` for reasons of memory management or window/widget collection management **as long as** you set the `Qt::Window` window flag on them.

Comment: what widgets come under transient parents other than popup?

Comment: I understood like which needs window management then it will have a transient parent !

Comment: @anilvalmiki Dialogs you open in your application are expected to be transient with you main window. This prevents the user from clicking the main window until the dialog closes. Note that Transient is an X-Window thing, not specific to Qt. It exists in Gnome too, for example.